# MDCContext got empty after i do run awaitSingle of a Mono (Spring webflux with kotlin suspend coroutine )

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I want to ask as why MDCContext got empty after calling awaitSingle of a Mono

here is snippet of the code

```
suspend fun getTemplates(request: GetPaginatedTemplateServiceRequest): PaginationTemplates {
        var context = MDCContext()
        val count = templateRepository.findByName(
            request.templateName
        ).awaitSingle()
        context = MDCContext()
}
```

for your information  templaterepository is using ReactiveMongo.

the first call of MDCContext, I have some `x-request-id` in the context map which i generated before that function

but after i call that awaitSingle with Mono, the MDCContext got empty (which I am not expected)

One solution that I try is to wrap awaitSingle with withContext function

example below

```
        var context = MDCContext()
        val count = withContext(Dispatchers.IO.plus(MDCContext())) {
            templateRepository.findTemplatesCount(
                request.templateName
            ).awaitSingle()
        }
        context = MDCContext()
```

then the second call of mdc context still containing items like the first call (which i expected).

I actually can use that solution, but there is so many already code that use awaitSingle like that.is there any simple solution for that? might be like automatically passing context to mono or something?

thankss, let me know if it is not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MDCContext` needs to be explicitly managed across the asynchronous boundaries. Unfortunately, `ReactiveMongo` does not inherently handle the propagation of this context.

There is not an automatic way to pass the context to every `Mono` operation, unless the reactive library explicitly supports this context propagation.
Some reactive frameworks might automatically propagate contexts, while others might not.

In essence, the **current solution of using `withContext` is the most practical method available** to maintain the context across `awaitSingle()` calls.

Continue using the `withContext` method you've already implemented to ensure context propagation; and consider encapsulating this into reusable utilities wrapping the asynchronous operations that require the context.

The following is a draft example of encapsulating the context propagation logic.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.slf4j.MDC
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

suspend fun <T> withMdcContext(block: suspend () -> T): T {
    val contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap() ?: emptyMap()
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO + MDCContext(contextMap)) {
        block()
    }
}

// Extension function for context preservation
fun <T> Mono<T>.preserveContext(): Mono<T> =
    this.subscriberContext { context ->
        val mdcContext = context.get(MDCContext::class.java)
        context + (mdcContext ?: MDCContext())
    }
```

Calling `preserveContext()` explicitly ensures that any context set before the reactive operation remains throughout the whole reactive chain.
It's a proactive step to safeguard context integrity in scenarios where the default behavior of context propagation might not be consistent across various reactive libraries.

```
suspend fun getTemplates(request: GetPaginatedTemplateServiceRequest): PaginationTemplates {
    val count = withMdcContext {
        templateRepository.findByName(request.templateName)
            .preserveContext() // Ensure context preservation in Mono
            .awaitSingle()
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, seems there is no other solution than this. thank you so much for explaining the preserve context.

Comment: what i do know is to create extension like `awaitSingleWithContext` and then process the awaitSingle with mdccontext called